# Launcher customization in unity?

Tags: customization

Is there a way to remove the bubble type deal that covers the icons on the unity launcher?
I've been looking to find a way to do this to make the theme on my launcher look better.
I haven't found anything in the unity tweaker that does this.
Are there any other tools I could use?

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by "bubble type deal that covers the icons on the unity launcher"? I don't get what you mean.

Comment: You could also use a more flexible desktop environment, such as XFCE.  Install it by running `sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop`.

Comment: just look for flat themes online and install one you like. Here's [one](http://www.noobslab.com/2015/08/looking-for-completely-flat-design.html)  and here's [another](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2015/11/flatabulous-flat-theme-ubuntu/). Both from two reputable sites in the Ubuntu blog world

Answer (score 0):

If I am correct, you can change and customize your launcher simply by installing a new theme.

To install it, open a `Terminal` and enter the following commands (for installing numix theme)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:numix/ppa

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install numix-gtk-theme numix-icon-theme-circle
```

Then, install the `Unity Tweak Tool`

```
sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
```

Open the Unity Tweak Tool and click on Theme

You can find more themes online just numix theme it's very popular.